# Rearranging array based on user choice

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

[enter image description here[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkkrx.png)I have an array which I read from file

[image: example of which I have in my array]

Something like this as shown in the figure.

1. I want to arrange it in an order that I check each array placing the least number in index0 and largest number in index2, the rest two numbers on index2,index3;
2. So this should be applied to all the data which ever I read from the file.
   Please help me with a good answer. When I try doing it considered every row as an index. I don't know how to take each element in a single row. Because my plan was to sort in based on place least element in index0 and largest in index1 but here it shows as index0 is a complete row.

For example i want output like this

```
['0','1','0.42673399999999995', '0.76885199999999998']
['0.76885200000000031','2','0.87031900000000029','1'] 
['0.8703189999999994','3','1.3058599999999998','2']
```

Comment: First line, shouldn't it be 0 instead of 0.42 for the first elemet since 0<0.42?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted first, then get the smallest element, the largest and put the rest behind.
So, based on your data:

```
import numpy

a = [[0, 0.42673399999999995, 1, 0.76885199999999998], 
    [1, 0.76885200000000031, 2, 0.87031900000000029], 
    [2, 0.8703189999999994, 3, 1.3058599999999998]]

a = numpy.sort(a, axis=1)
a = numpy.hstack((a[:,0][:,None], a[:,-1][:,None], a[:,1:-1]))

print a
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.        1.        0.426734  0.768852]
 [ 0.768852  2.        0.870319  1.      ]
 [ 0.870319  3.        1.30586   2.      ]]
```

**Edit** Version that reads the CSV file:

```
import numpy

a = []
filename = open( "doc.csv" )
for line in filename.readlines():
    a.append(line.strip().split(","))
a = numpy.sort(a, axis=1)
a = numpy.hstack((a[:,0][:,None], a[:,-1][:,None], a[:,1:-1]))

print a
```

New output:

```
[['0' '1' '0.42673399999999995' '0.76885199999999998']
 ['0.76885200000000031' '2' '0.87031900000000029' '1']
 ['0.8703189999999994' '3' '1.3058599999999998' '2']]
```

Please check that you don't have any blank line at the end of your CSV file (if you have but can't change your CSV file, this can be fixed by adding a condition before `a.append(...)`)

Comment: I get this error-   a.sort(axis, kind, order)
ValueError: axis(=1) out of bounds

Comment: @sana Can you provide the exact format of **a** in your question? I guess we don't have the exact same format

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But does it alters the least number at index0 and largest number in index1 for whatever array i read for file?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. It does not alter any number, since they are just sorted then exchange. My output is just different because it was float numbers and not strings, but the code works identically.

Comment: Please see the updated question i have added the output.csv which i want to read in my file.

Comment: @sana Use the least possible number of images, as it is more difficult for us to see what's wrong. I can't do anything with this, what i need is -from your code- the way data are stored. How do you read them, in which type of variables do you store them etc, and for that, you have to include some code... Else i won't be able to help you more

Comment: txt = open( "/Users/tej/Desktop/TSAlgorithm/Rots/outputdoc.csv" ) for line in txt.readlines(): text = line.strip().split(",") . (This is how i am reading my data and keeping it as an array)

Comment: @sana See the edit of my post, it should solve the problem

Comment: @sana If it suits you, please mark the post as answered, else please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't expect my problem get solved this fast.